# JIRA SOAP API : link an issue to another

Tags: api, jira

I'm working on a tool in C# that interfaces the JIRA SOAP API. I have read the [documentation](http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/index.html) but I can't find what I'm looking for. Does anyone know if it is possible to link an issue to another one via this api?

PS : Actually, my real need is to convert an issue as a subtask of an issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I looked, JIRA's web service wasn't really actively supported or encouraged by Atlassian. It's very much a second-class citizen compared to the web front end, with very basic operations.

Also, it's not a WSI-compliant web service (it's an old Axis-based RPC_encoded service), and so modern web service stacks won't even bind to it.  You might want check that your client can perform basic query operations before diving into the depths of the API.

Comment: hmm after a quick look on some other sites, I'm affraid you're right... it seems that I won't be able to go very far with this API...

Comment: Does anyone know if this feature has been added to the SOAP API? It has been about three years since this post... (Also, I only need to link two issues.)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually go pretty far with Jelly scripts, but converting an issue to a subtask then linking it as a subtask... I'm not positive that you can go that far.